# Group by and reduce to a json list

Tags: java, json, java-stream

Hi have native sql query which returns List interface class with 3 fields

Trying to find a clean efficient way to do this to reduce to sub-list

Appreciate help

Thanks

**SQL query**
List  findResponse();

**Response class**

```
public interface Response {
    Long getId();

    String getSData();

    String getSName();
}
```

**The query result converted to json looks as**

```
[
{"id":1,"sData":"UK,FR","sName":"X},
{"id":2,"sData":"UK,FR","sName":"Y"},
{"id":4,"sData":"EU","sName":"X"},
{"id":4,"sData":"Others","sName":"O"}
]
```

**Expected Output For ex for id=4**

```
{
    “subData” :
          [
              {
                 “sData”: “X”,
                 “sName”: “EU”
              },
              {
                 "sName": "O",
                 "sData": "Others"
              }
          ]
    }
```

I can create another class if needed

```
@Data
public class NewResponse {

    public Long id;
    public List<subData> subDataList;
}
```

Comment: Share your code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start off by grouping to a map:

```
Map<Long> grouped = responses.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Response::getId,
                mapping(r -> new SubData(r.getSData(), r.getSName()), toList())));
```

Then you can stream the Map entries to convert them to `NewResponse`s:

```
List<NewResponse> mapped = grouped.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(e -> new NewResponse(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
        .collect(toList());
```

Feel free to chain the operations if you don't want the extra `grouped` variable.

Comment: Thanks I was able to solve it using mapping.